# Xcode downloading update in the background?

Tags: macos, updates, xcode, automatic-update, auto-updates

I often see Xcode downloading heavily and it's not clear what.

1. I did not download it through the App store - and do not see anything updating there.
2. There are no automatic simulator updates and nothing seems to be downloading in the settings tab.
3. I see there is the strange location suggesting it could be coming from the simulator (or to the simulator?) but there are no UI mechanisms for checking/getting updates on iOS simulators.

Any idea what it could be?

cdn-apple.com

updates-http.cdn-apple.com

[image]

Comment: The similar issue on my side. The traffic comes from `nsurlsessiond (iOS) -> cdn.apple.com -> updates-http.cdn-apple.com`. Have to block this traffic in LS :)